# z = arctan(Y/X) where Y and X are random variables. How to define z from 0 to 2*pi?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

*EDITED*

The title is pretty much self-explanatory.

I'm trying to find a pdf of phase of a vector Z which is defined as Z = X + i*Y

X and Y are iid random variables with Gaussian distributions of **nonzero mean**.

One way to find a phase would be to use arctan(Y/X). However, using arctan would result in an answer between -pi/2 and pi/2. I am interested in the actual phase from 0 to 2 pi.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `atan2` ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: All decent computing systems offer this service in the form of an "ATan2" function or the equivalent.  The "phase" is defined to be the imaginary component of the complex logarithm, often called the "argument" of Z.  For instance, `R` directly implements this with its `Arg` function, which is applied directly to Z itself: no need to extract X and Y first.  The mathematical convention is to return a value in the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$ but that is easy enough to change, such as by adding $2\pi$ and reducing the result modulo $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The usual range of $\arctan$ will be on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. You can define an inverse on some other interval of width $\pi$ (a different definition of $\arctan$ from the standard one) by moving left or right along the x-axis for $\tan$ and taking your inverse so that it corresponds.

If you want the result of *arctan* to be on $(0,2\pi)$ you would look defining *tan* on that domain and see how to invert that. But we immediately see a problem:

[image]

in that *tan* goes through two cycles in that time. There's no unique inverse. You *can't* simply shift the phase - $tan(x+\phi)$ - and avoid this problem.

So you can't do what you seem to be asking for.

Stéphane's suggestion of the atan2 function seems to do what it sounds like you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, my question wasn't on the definition of the tangent, but a way to go about finding a phase such that I can find a phase of a random variable vector that is defined from 0 to 2 pi.

Comment: Your comment is unclear. "Choosing a phase" would simply move you left or right along the x-axis of tan, resulting in exactly the same problem shown in my second image- if you choose an interval wider than $\pi$, you'll always get $y=tan(x)$ having more than one $x$ for a given $y$, so it's not invertible. The point of the later part of my answer is that you don't have any way of choosing an interval of width $2\pi$ to give you what you ask for.

Comment: See the edited answer.